# power query - List.Distinct function how to apply it

Tags: powerquery

I'm doing lab power query and testing lab how to use List.Distinct function.
It always give me the error (I'll attach the photo)
my query code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Subject", type text}, {"Body.TextBody", type text}, {"Id", type text}, {"Sender Add", type text}, {"To Add", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Body.TextBody", "Subject"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Sender Add"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Custom", each List.Distinct([To Add]), type text)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Update the error screenshot
[image]

[image]

I would like to remove duplicate email in the column To Add and put them in the new column
Could you please help assist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the distinct items from each row into a new column adjacent to each row, try

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"priorstep", "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct(Text.Split([To Add],"; ")),"; "))
```

If you are trying to get the distinct items from all the rows at once, try

```
= Table.FromList(List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform((Source[To Add]), each Text.Split(_,"; ")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform that text into a list.

Try using [Text.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/powerquery-m/text-split) for example.

Did not test it but should be something like this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Subject", type text}, {"Body.TextBody", type text}, {"Id", type text}, {"Sender Add", type text}, {"To Add", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Body.TextBody", "Subject"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Sender Add"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Custom", each List.Distinct(Text.Split([To Add],";")), type text)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

and then expanding your Custom Field.